# Convert string to float32?

Tags: go

There is an input that I need to read from the console as a string, then manipulate the string and convert some of it to `float32`.

I have tried using:

```
float, _ := strconv.ParseFloat(myString, 32)
```

But it does not work. This is the error I get:

> cannot use float (type float64) as type float32 in field value

Is there anything else I could do?
Thanks!

Comment: instead of ignoring the error with `_`, why not assign it `err` and paste the error message here?

Comment: I edited my original post with the error i get

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`float` has the type `float32`, but [`strconv.ParseFloat`](https://godoc.org/strconv#ParseFloat) returns `float64`. All you need to do is convert the result:

```
// "var float float32" up here somewhere
value, err := strconv.ParseFloat(myString, 32)
if err != nil {
    // do something sensible
}
float = float32(value)
```

Depending on the situation, it may be better to change `float`'s type to `float64`.